# chart.js remove on hover effect

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When you hover on top of your bars in chart.js it turns to a lighter color. How do i turn that off so it always keep the regular color?

This is how it looks normally:
[image: before hovering]

This is how it look when you over over any bar:
[image: after hovering]

This is the code i use to display my chart:

```
data-scales='{"yAxes": [{
   "ticks": { 
       "beginAtZero": "true", 
       "max": 3,
       "stepSize": 1,
       "fontSize": 0,
       "mirror": "true"
   }
   }],
   "xAxes": [{
       "barPercentage": 0.5
   }]
}' 
data-hide='["gridLinesX","tooltips", "legend"]'
```

Answer (score 24):

Just set the `hoverBackgroundColor` property to the same value as `backgroundColor`.  Then on hover will not change the bar color.

Here is an example​ of how your data object would look like using the `hoverBackgroundColor`.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to disable the hover effect and hide tooltips, remove the hover event from the configuration: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html

I'm guessing that you don't want any events (just like I did on my chart), so pass this in your options

```
options: { events: [] }
```

-- Edit -- See below, You should do the following to avoid the warning that they now give.

```
options: { events: null }
```

Comment: I would rather use `options: { events: null }` to avoid a warning.

Comment: If they now emit a warning I'd recommend doing null as well